# Is it possible to move between desktops with mouse wheel?

Tags: 11.10, mouse-scroll

Is it possible to move between desktops with mouse wheel in 11.10?

I could do this in earlier versions using ccsm but that doesn't seem to work in 11.10

Thanks in advance. Bob.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to 'scroll on desktop' that still works fine -

ccsm > Viewport Switcher > Desktop-based viewport switching, typically 'Move Next' - button 5, 'Move Prev' - button 4

It works ok with the default Wall & 2X2 workspaces though you might want to slow down a bit in Wall's settings.

It's not uncommon that some ccsm changes won't be realized until you restart compiz or do a log out/in, don't think this is one of them but you never know..

Rotate/cube may work for you, presently is quite broken for many with flashing of previous window when switching workspaces, still an open bug on that.